# How to change the reply email address to the queue's email address when replying from dynamic crm 2011?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, jscript

What i want to do is when we click on Reply button , the From address field will be populate with the email-id (default team's default queue's email-id). Current scenario is populated with logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

You can create script which will be executed onLoad of email form. Check is it 'Replay' action (Url will contain _InReplyToId parameter). Find queue from original email using his GUID from url, and set it to From field.

EDIT:
This [example](http://m-atif.blogspot.com/2012/04/changing-reply-email-address-to-queues.html) will solve your problem :)